Differentiable Structure on topological Manifold given by one function
I have given a family of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ by $$\varphi_r(t):= \begin{cases}t &&\text{ if  } t\leq 0 \\ rt &&\text{ if } t>0\end{cases}$$ and have to show that they each give a differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}$ but each of them gives a different one.
I know that I have to show that the charts are not compatible to show that they define different structures, but I don't know how to show that each of them defines a differentiable structure or what it means that one function generates a differentiable structure. If I had two charts I would simply show that the transition map is differentiable, but how can I use this here?

There's almost nothing to show for the positive part. Read the definition of atlas carefully, and if you only have one function that covers your entire space, you'll see that the transition map has to be the Identity map from R to R.
